# VS2010 loses breakpoint hits on upgrade from VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I develop some C# Add-Ins for the Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect UML modelling product.
The Add-In was being developed under VS2008 and all was fine.
I thought I'd upgrade to VS2010 and the upgrade appeared to work without error (or as far as can see any substantive warnings).  However, I can't trigger any breakpoints under VS2010.  I can set them but when the code runs under the IDE, the code doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

The PDB files are being created and the source and binaries are in synch.  I found some references on the net (and in Stack Overflow) to issues with breakpints and web development, but I'm just developing COM aware Add-Ins with no fancy stuff.  I tried some of those solutions "on spec" to no avail.

Anyone got any ideas why the upgrade has resulted in this?

TIA,
Paolo

Comment: If you make a change to the code, are the changes showing up on execution?

Comment: Be sure to install VS2010 Service Pack 1.  It has important debugger fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue a couple months ago with breakpoints not stopping.  I ultimately installed the [service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5) like @Hans Passant mentioned and it fixed my issues.  I've also read that reinstalling VS2010 will fix it, but I think you should just go for the service pack.

Comment: Sorry, I've been remiss in confirming tha tthe Service pack as suggested by Hans does, indeed, solve the problems I was having.